# Question about substitution when solving PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I encountered a way of solving PDE, which makes me confused.

Suppose we have

$a(x,y)u_x+b(x,y)u_y+c(x,y)u=f$  $\Omega$, I will use $a$ to represent $a(x,y)$ in the following.

To make it solvable, we use some substitutions.

$\xi=\xi(x,y), \eta=\eta(x,y)$, and the Jacobi determinant at some $(x_0,y_0)\in \Omega$ is not zero. By using the chain rule, we have a new equation.

$(a\xi_x+b\xi_y)\mu_\xi+(a\eta_x+b\eta_y)\mu_\eta+c\mu=f$ $\cdots (2)$.

> My question is

1. what is the relationship between the solutions to these two equations?
2. does the second one a first-order PDE? Do we need to change all the elements through the inverse substitution, i.e. $x=x(\xi, \eta), y=(\xi, \eta)$ to make it a PDE of $\xi$ and $\eta$.
3. if the answer to the second is yes, then using the implicit existence and unique theorem, we know that only in some **neighborhood** of $(\xi_0=\xi(x_0,y_0), \eta_0=\eta(x_0,y_0))$, the inverse exists and unique, so we can only have the second equation reasonable only at that neighborhood?

After that, we began to show how to find $\eta$ and $ \xi$. If the coefficient is zero, then it will be easy to solve. So
we let $(a\xi_x+b\eta_y)=0 $$\cdots (4)$, but

4. On which domain should the  $(4)$ satisfy? On the original $\Omega$? coz it can represent a PDE of $x$ and $y$, On the neighborhood of $(\xi_0,\eta_0)$ coz we have already used the substitution?

I think 'on $\Omega$' is more reasonable, so I continue the method.

5. Suppose we have some $\phi(x)$ satisfies $(a\phi_x+b\phi_y)=0$ on $\Omega$, now we can solve $(2)$, we will have $\mu= g(\xi, \eta)$ on the neighborhood, then by substitution we have $\mu=g(x,y)$ on $\Omega$?

I am new to PDE, so it may be tedious, appreciate your helping hands.

Comment: Hint to answer the first question: $\mu(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=u(x,y)$. Can you use the chain rule to relate $\mu_\xi,\mu_\eta$ to $u_x$ and $u_y$ ?

Comment: I know that, but in fact, my question is what is the relationship between the solutions to the two equations?

Comment: The relationship is $\mu(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=u(x,y)$.

Comment: Do you mean, As I asked in question 5, if we find the $\mu=f(\xi, \eta)$, then we have $\mu=f(x,y)$ on $\Omega$?

Comment: Not at all. The function $f$ is the component that makes the PDE inhomogeneous. I gather that the goal is to choose the variable transformation by the functions $\xi,\eta$ such that $(a\xi_x+b\color{red}{\xi}_y)=0$ (there seems a typo in your eq. (4)). This simplifies the transformed PDE to $(a\eta_x+b\eta_y)\mu_\eta+c\mu=f$ . It is probably best if you make up a few concrete examples and apply this to functions with flesh and blood. Don't stay in that abstract world.

Comment: Where did you encounter this solution method ? It looks like if one can find two injective functions $\xi,\eta$ on $\Omega$ such that $a\xi_x+b\xi_y=0$ and $a\eta_x+b\eta_y=0$ then the solution of the PDE is in fact $u(x,y)=\mu(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=f(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))/c$.

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry, it is a typo. It is not $f$. In fact, if we can get one of the constants to zero, it can be solved as an ODE.